# "User Sortable Items" UPDATE-ed to Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to use [this jQuery-UI-sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/display-grid.html) in a project 
What is the best practice to UPDATE the database after the user has finished sorting it?
Should I update on every release? OR have the user sort first and then press "Save"?
Also how do I retrieve the new order of the items and then update the database?
I'm thinking JSON Array + hidden form for the ID but I'm still confused. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, put a button "Save", automatically saving at each release is not only dangerous but also very confusing for the user, a "Save" button is straightforward.

As for how, yeah, a JSON array that you send to your back-end and that's it.